# Gamma and a poisson distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

[image]

All I know is that $P(X=x)=e^{-5x}\frac{5^x}{x!}$ where $x\geq 0$. The formula that im using is $E(Y)=\int E(Y|X=x)f_x(x) dx $ where $f_x(s)\int f(x,y) dy $=. Also I guess that from the hint that $E(Y|X=x)=\int_{0}^{\infty} y f(y|x) dy= \dfrac{k}{10}$. From here im lost how to find $E(Y)$. Thanks

Comment: Try $$f(y)=\int_0^\infty f(x,y)\ dx, \quad\text{where}\ f(x,y)=f(y|x)f(x).$$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: That certainly won't help the OP, since your formula would yield $f(y)=0$ for all $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a Z ~ Gamma ($\alpha~,~ \beta $)

$$
f(z)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}z^{\alpha -1}e^{-\beta z}
$$

Using Iterated Expectation:

$$
\Bbb E[~Y~]=\Bbb E_X~[~\Bbb E_{Y|X}~[~Y~|~X~]~]=\Bbb E_X~[~\frac{x}{10}~]=\frac{1}{10}\Bbb E_X~[~x~]=\frac{5}{10}
$$

Hope this helps